# strtotime to time issue with a specific date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a strange behavior with the following code:

```
echo strftime('%B %G', strtotime('2017-01-01')) . ' - weird..';
echo '<br>';
echo strftime('%B %G', strtotime('2017-01-02')) . ' - all good!';
```

Result:

```
January 2016 - weird..
January 2017 - all good!
```

I don't know why the date **2017-01-01** is giving me this wrong result.
I expect to have **January 2017** obviously.

Any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah funny one ;)

As you can [read in the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

> %g    Two digit representation of the year going by ISO-8601:1988 standards (see %V)

Going by ISO-8601:1988 means according to the week.
So if you check your calendar, 2017-01-01 is sunday. You can verify it like that:

```
➜  ~ php -r "echo strftime('%u', strtotime('2017-01-01'));"
7%
```

So 2017-01-01 belongs to the last week of 2016!
You will have the same behavior with 2016-01-01, 2016-01-02, and 2016-01-03

```
➜  ~ php -r "echo strftime('%B %G', strtotime('2016-01-03'));"
January 2015%
```

To be safe, use `%Y`

Comment: Awesome!
Now it makes way more sense. Thanks!